# ImportError: cannot import name '_get_logger' Niftynet

Tags: python, tensorflow, niftynet

I'm trying to run Niftynet on my PC. but it keeps showing this error. I had a CPU version for tensorflow and it worked. After that I installed tensorflow-gpu and now it stopped working.

Please do note that import tensorflow as tf works fine so I'm not sure what do to now to solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\halim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\halim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\halim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\net_run.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\halim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\niftynet\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    set_logger()
  File "c:\users\halim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\niftynet\io\misc_io.py", line 724, in set_logger
    from tensorflow.python.platform.tf_logging import _get_logger
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_logger'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install only `tensorflow-gpu`, and install the correct version for it. First uninstall everything:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu tensorflow
```

Then reinstall the correct tensorflow-gpu version

```
pip3 install --user tensorflow-gpu==1.12
```

The version is mentioned in the installation guide: https://niftynet.readthedocs.io/en/dev/installation.html